# Static members and static globals in memory

Tags: c++, global-variables, static-variables

Lets consider two cases:

1.) Static global variables. 
When i generate map file i can't find static global variables in .bss or .data section.

2.) Static members

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <list>
    #include <algorithm>

    using namespace std;

    class Tree {
        struct Node {
            Node(int i, int d): id(i), dist(d) {}
            int id;
            int dist; // distance to the parent node
            list<Node*> children;
        };

        class FindNode {
            static Node* match;
            int id;
        public:
            FindNode(int i): id(i) {}
            Node* get_match()
            {
                return match;
            }

            bool operator()(Node* node)
            {
                if (node->id == id) {
                    match = node;
                    return true;
                }
                if (find_if(node->children.begin(), node->children.end(), FindNode(id)) != node->children.end()) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };

        Node* root;

        void rebuild_hash();
        void build_hash(Node* node, Node* parent = 0);

        vector<int> plain;
        vector<int> plain_pos;
        vector<int> root_dist;
        bool hash_valid; // indicates that three vectors above are valid

        int ncount;
    public:
        Tree(): root(0), ncount(1) {}
        void add(int from, int to, int d);
        int get_dist(int n1, int n2);

    };

    Tree::Node* Tree::FindNode::match = 0;
...
```

Variable Tree::FindNode::match is static member of FindNode class. And this variable is presented in map file in bss section. Why so??

```
 *(.bss)
 .bss           0x00408000       0x80 C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\яндекс\runs\runs\\000093.obj
                0x00408000                _argc
                0x00408004                _argv
                0x00408020                Tree::FindNode::match
```

I use MinGW, os windows 7. All object files obtained by g++ ...cpp -o ...obj command, map file obtained by ld ....obj -Map .....map command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Global variables are already in the static memory, so C re-used the existing keyword `static` to make a global variable "file-scoped", and C++ followed the suite. The keyword `static` hides your global from the map file.

Static members, on the other hand, are class-scoped, therefore they need to be available in the map file: other modules need to be able to access the static members of your class, both member functions and member variables, even if they are separately compiled.

Comment: thanks. one more question, please, - so how can i distinguish static and global variables in map file, is it possible?

Comment: @AlexHoppus C-style static variables are excluded from the map file, so if you see a variable in a map file, and it does not have `::` in its name, it's a C-style global; if it has `::`, it's a static member of a class.

Comment: yes but if it is global variable included into namespace? namespace::variable_name

Comment: @AlexHoppus Oh, you are right, I can't think of a way to distinguish the two kinds of variables by looking at the map file. It does not make much difference to a map file, anyway, because a static member of a class and a global variable in a namespace are essentially the same as far as the linker is concerned.

Comment: I think i can check if smth is behind :: is a class or function name, which i can find in this map file, than it's static variable